# Spring Cloud Config property value sent in plaintext over https

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud-config

On Spring Cloud Config security documentation found [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_security) it's stated that

```
If the remote property sources contain encrypted content (values starting with {cipher}), they are decrypted before sending to clients over HTTP
```

Doesn't it defeat the purpose of securing the message if you are sending it in plaintext via http?

If we are using https with properly configured security certificates. The decrypted property values data integrity and confidentiality will be taken care of?

Answer (score 2):

If the property is encrypted and shared by SCC server over HTTP with decryption on server side, than indeed it will be send over HTTP in plain text. This setup makes sense if:

1. **You're concerned with securing property value on rest.** So people with access to config repo won't be able to obtain the value of the secret property. Also it protects in case the access to config repo is compromised.
2. **You're not concerned with securing property value in transit.** For instance, your application server and SCC server are both in a protected segment of your network like DMZ.

So the answer to your question is *generally NO*, the purpose of securing the data is not defeated in certain cases.

However, if you need to protect your config properties in transit too, but you're limited with HTTP between SCC and app servers, then you can setup **client-side decryption**. To achieve this you'll have to setup a keystore on application server with proper keys and disable decryption on server side.